# How to print in 2 html using one javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have 2 html files and now I am printing everythinng in 1 of the htmls. When I click a button I want to print everything on the 2nd HTML. Here are the codes

questionaire: 1st html
questionaire1: 2nd html

HTML1:

```
<head>
  <title>Your Survey Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="DemoSurveyStyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="alternate stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ol id="menu">
    <li> <a href="DemoSurvey.html">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="new.html">CreateSurvey</a> </li>
  </ol>
  <h1 id="myText" contenteditable="true">Survey Name</h1>
  <div id="buttons">
  <button type="button" id="addSectionButton">Add Section</button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- <button type="button" id="copyButton">Duplicate Survey</button> -->
  <button type="button" id="clearButton">Clear Survey</button>
  <button type="button" id="testButton">Test</button>

  <p id="testingBox">testingBox</p> <p id="testingBox1">testingBox1</p>
  <p id="testingBox2">testingBox2</p> <p id="testingBox3">testingBox3</p>
  <p id="testingBox4">testingBox4</p>
  <p id="testingBox5">testingBox5</p> <p id="testingBox6">testingBox6</p>
  <p id="testingBox7">testingBox7</p>
  <form>
    <div id="questionaire"></div>
  </form>

  <p class="counters" id="numberOfOptionsQuestions"></p>
  <p class="counters" id="numberOfShAnQuestions"></p>
  <p class="counters" id="numberOfLoAnQuestions"></p>
  <p class="counters" id="numberOfNumQuestions"></p>
  <p class="counters" id="numberOfStarQuestions"></p>
  <p class="counters" id="testingText"></p>

  <script src="DemoCode.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

HTML2:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Your Survey Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="DemoSurveyStyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="alternate stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <ol id="menu">
        <li> <a href="DemoSurvey.html">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="new.html">CreateSurvey</a> </li>
    </ol>
    <button type="button" id="copyButton">Duplicate Survey</button>
    <p id="testingBox10">testingBox10</p>
  <form>
    <div id="questionaire1"></div>
  </form>
  
  <script src="DemoCode.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And the part of Javascript that prints:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < allSectionsArray.length; i++) {
        newSection(true, allSectionsArray[i][0]);
        for (let j = 0; j < allSectionsArray[i][3].length; j++) {
            switch (allSectionsArray[i][3][j][1]) {
                case 0:
                    newOption(questionnaire.querySelector("div.section:last-child ul"), true, j, i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    newShAnSubquestion(questionnaire.querySelector("div.section:last-child ul"), true, j, i);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    newLoAnSubquestion(questionnaire.querySelector("div.section:last-child ul"), true, j, i);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    newNumSubquestion(questionnaire.querySelector("div.section:last-child ul"), true, j, i);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    newStarSubquestion(questionnaire.querySelector("div.section:last-child ul"), true, j, i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print everything on questionaire1 but simply changing to questionaire1 in javascript when I print doesn't seem to work

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are writing to one html but then you want  to change it and write in another one?

Comment: Yea thats exactly what I want to do

Comment: Rather than having 2 files, wouldn't it be easier to have all content in one HTML file. make q1 display block and q2 display none by default. later on according to your needs, then you make q1 display none and q2 display block? or something like that. why would you need 2 seperate files?

Comment: Because I am creating a survey. When I click to print I want everything to be printed on the 2nd HTML page. The first is used to create the survey. Now when I click print one is under the other

Comment: Still you could have an invisible div where you render the page you want to print and use `@media print` CSS where that div is then shown [@media docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

Comment: Thats a good idea, can I make invisible the first part after im done with it and print the new one that I wanted on the new HTML?

Comment: Yes exactly. Why not try that out and create a new question if you discover problems.